# Maximo’s Birt Export Data function does not export all rows

Tags: eclipse, birt, maximo

Maximo’s Birt Export Data function does not export all rows

Background (Birt Report designer 2.3.2 || Maximo Version 7.1.1.8

1. I created a BIRT report using Maximo Group template that returns
   Purchase Order information including PO_NUM, Item_Num, Quantity,
   etc. – Grouped by PO_NUM
2. In my case the report returns a Purchase Order Number and a list of
   all of the Items on the that Purchase Order
3. The report returns correctly in the Birt designer and in Maximo.
4. The ‘Export Report’ function works correctly from within Maximo returning each Purchase order and a list of all of the items for each Purchase Order
5. When I use the ‘Export Data’ function from Maximo the export function only returns the first two items from the total list of items for each Purchase Order. For example PO# 3526 has six items, however the ‘Export Data’ function only returns two of the six.